# Stop browser caching images to disk

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, caching, browser

I'm developing a local application that displays sensitive images from a secure local server and I need to ensure those images are only viewable inside my web application - so I don't want them stored on disk (via cache or anything like that).

Here are my response headers (nodejs express):

```
res.header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
res.header("Pragma", "no-cache");
res.header("Expires", "0");
res.send(image);
```

Here is my AngularJS code to get the image and render it. I'm using AJAX because I'm authenticating the user via JWT so I need to include the auth header.

```
$http.get(src, {
    responseType: 'arraybuffer'
})
.then(function(res){
    var headers = res.headers();
    var blob = new Blob([res.data], {
        type: headers['content-type']
    });

    image.src = $window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
});
```

It seems to work but I'm confused as to what the Chrome and Firefox developer tools are showing me. I need to be 100% sure these images aren't stored on disk.

But I see:

```
Status Code: 200 OK (from cache)
```

[Chrome Dev Tools Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZzqA.png)

I can't see the image in the chrome://cache tab but it worries me that I'm seeing (from cache) in the network monitor.

In my Firefox cache viewer I see the url to the image but the device column says "memory". Can anyone who's looking at memory view it after some period of time, especially after a user has logged out?

[Firefox cache viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K8oQ.png)

So I guess my real question is what are these two browsers doing when I create a blob? And can anyone access these images outside the browser? What does it do on a mobile/tablet device?

If I were to transfer the image using a base64 string, would that be safer or worse in terms of privacy and security?

Comment: Besides caching... you're aware that users could simply save the image to disk if they really wanted to?

Comment: User could take a screenshot of document.

Comment: _“If I were to transfer the image using a base64 string, would that be safer or worse in terms of privacy and security?”_ – it would be the exact same thing.

Comment: What will happen with cache, if after image load you will do $window.URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src) ? Will it disappear from cache?

Comment: @deceze that's true but the user is already authorised to view the images so if they save it to disk/take a screen shot that's their responsibility. I just wanted to know if the application was leaving a trace of the image on the device.

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can convert jpg blob to canvas image data, by [jpg.js](https://github.com/eugeneware/jpeg-js) and then load it to a canvas, and don't use images, in this case, there are any no images and resources to load by HTTP.